# How to open the remote host's terminal on Godaddy and execute commands?

Tags: ssh, shared-hosting, godaddy-api

I use ssh2 to open the remote host's terminal and execute commands from Ubuntu and works successfully.
However, when I execute ssh commands like `ssh user@hostname` in Godaddy shared host's terminal and it doesn't work. It's seems like Godaddy's shared host doesn't support ssh to do this work.

I tried netcat command in Godaddy shared host's terminal and it doesn't work either. What else methods can I try to finish this work?

Comment: I use putty, it works, I have lowest version